# Selenium Python Iterate over li elements inside ol

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to extract, using python and selenium,  the text of multiple li elements, all of them, inside an ol element.
The list is like this:

```
/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2
/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2
/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2
/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2
...
```

So far, I'm using the following code, but this code shows only one element, and not the whole list.
What is wrong with it?
Thanks!

```
articles_list=r'/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol'
articles_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(articles_list)

for article in articles_elements:
    title = article.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2').text
    print('Title:'+title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `li` tag has **increment indices** like `[3]` then `[4]` and so on..

You can look for each and every web element by declaring `i = 3`, initially and then **increment** using **programmatically**.

```
a = 3
size_of_list  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li")
for i in range(size_of_list):
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/main/div/div/section/ol/li[{a}]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/h2").text
    print('Title:', title)
    a = a +1
```

Comment: For some unknown reasons.. with this code, it is still iterating over the first element. Don't know why

Comment: @CristianAvendaño : The logic was incorrect, I have corrected it, please try again.